# Decorator Factory

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

The factory accepts a function (lambda) as an input and returns a decorator that will return the result of the function as the first argument. The result of the decorated function is passed. The function that the factory accepts (in the example below, it is a lambda) can only take one positional parameter.

**Example:**

```py
@decorator_apply(lambda user_id: user_id + 1)
def return_user_id(num: int):
    return num
    
return_user_id(42) 
>>>43
```

Answer (score 1):

Just nest functions until you reach the required depth, then apply them:

```py
def decorator_apply(transform):
    def wrapper(f):
        def wrapped(x, /):
            return f(transform(x))
        return wrapped
    return wrapper


@decorator_apply(lambda user_id: user_id + 1)
def return_user_id(num: int):
    return num

return_user_id(42)
```